# Free Topical Taxonomy (Classification System) for Commerical Use

Tags: classification, taxonomy

I am looking for a free taxonomy that is totally free. In my research, Dewey has legal problem. Library of Congress Classification is copyrighted except in the USA. DMOZ requires update from users. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, is there any totally free taxonomy for commerical use?

What I am looking for is something like a Google Directory or Yahoo Directory.

Comment: scope = ? covering everything? or one specific area? how is this related to programming?

Comment: Thanks, I have added "non-programming related" tag. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps there is an earlier edition of the DDC that is now out of copyright, it was developed some time in the late 1800's.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found the original version (yr 1876) of DDC at Gutenberg.

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/12513/12513-h/12513-h.htm

Does anyone have the latest version that in the public domain?